# Sprint backlog before going further with project

Tags: scrum, sprint, project-management-style, sprint-backlog

I've an ongoing project with very tight deadline. I'm allowed to extend project deadline, if required. I've implemented Scrum (sprints).

Issue is - I've some backlog since one weeks, that I couldn't arrange to complete. I must complete project backlog, before I go further with project.

What should be better at this stage, from following options?

- Extend current/next sprint and complete backlog with it. Do sprint allows the same?
- Create a new sprint and add between existing project flow. i.e. Upon completion of current sprint, should I add backlog sprint in between.
- Should I add new resources to team or ask my team for overtime? (I don't think it's better way.)

Any other proper solution for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Extend current/next sprint and complete backlog with it.

Generally a bad idea. Sprints are meant to be time-boxed. Meaning, their start and end dates are fixed. They are sometimes ended/aborted early, but they should not be extended.

> Create a new sprint and add between existing project flow.

Not 100% sure but what I'm getting from that is that you've set up all of your Sprints ahead of time, and are now asking if you can add a new Sprint in the middle. *Don't set up all your Sprints ahead of time*. You should only have two 'buckets' for stories/tasks; the product backlog or the *current* Sprint. As new work is discovered, add it to the backlog. During the sprintly Planning Meeting, take the highest-priority stories from the task that the Development Team thinks it can complete, and move them into the next Sprint. You don't need to (and shouldn't) plan multiple Sprints in advance.

> Should I add new resources to team or ask my team for overtime?

In general, a bad idea. There are *some* situations where this can work, but it shouldn't be your first option.

Answer (score 3):

[Scrum](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) is a framework for complex **product** development.  Most [**project** management](https://www.pmi.org/about/learn-about-pmi/what-is-project-management) approaches are counter to the framework and the values and principles of [agile software development](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

Perhaps [kanban](https://leankit.com/learn/kanban/what-is-kanban/) is a better fit for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

> Issue is - I've some backlog since two weeks, that I couldn't arrange
>   to complete.

Why? Are you conducting [sprint retrospective](https://www.scrumalliance.org/community/articles/2014/april/key-elements-of-sprint-retrospective) meeting with your team? Because in sprint retrospective, the team discusses the just-concluded sprint and determines what could be changed that might make the next sprint more productive.

May be you can bring up this issue in your sprint retrospective and discuss with the team as why the backlog items (which I am assuming were part of sprint deliverables) are not completed?

Usually in sprint retro, team members discuss the process that they are following and give any suggestions for improvement and discuss any other ideas that could improve their productivity.

I think your first challenge is to identify "why" backlog items are not addressed and then based on your findings, you/scrum team can decide "how" to address it.